# How to bypass API key validity check in AWS CloudFormation Console rollback

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I tried to perform an update using AWS Amplify, and the update failed due to a mistake I made in the configuration.

That's not a problem, but the issue is that the rollback from my failed update also failed, so now the stack is in a state of 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED'. My goal is try to complete that rollback so I can get back on track.

The reason the rollback is failing is due to an AppSync API error that appears every time I try to rerun the rollback.
'API key must be valid for a minimum of 1 days.'

I understand from looking at this github conversation (linked below) that I can rerun the rollback in a way that bypasses the API key validation check, but I do not now how exactly to do this, and would greatly appreciate any pointers on how this can be done.

This github conversation covers an almost identical issue to mine, but they miss out the explanation on how exactly to bypass the validation check when rerunning the rollback. It seems to work for them, I just don't know how to do it.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/1040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you CloudFormation are stuck into the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state your need to trigger a force rollback and ignore the stack there hit the error, the command for that is

```
aws cloudformation continue-update-rollback --stack-name awsstackname123 --resources-to-skip awsfaultyresource123
```

You can read more here https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudformation-update-rollback-failed